# Original file turns modified after "Save for Web..." in Photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, photoshop-cs5, illustrator-cs6

What happens to the edited file after saving its copy using the "Save for Web…" command? Why the original, unmodified file turns into "changed" (with "*" symbol after its name)?

P. S. The same behaviour is in the Adobe Illustrator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you save for web, the file remembers those preferences (save for web preferences are saved in the actual file).

So, next time you open the file and save for web, the save for web preferences will be just like previously.  Its basically a history-recorded thing in PS, so the asterisk pops up to note that "Hey, the .psd or .ai has things that aren't saved."